# Accessing scope within link function in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a scope in my main controller, and then I feed in an isolate scope into my link function. Is there any way to also access the main scope from my link function? Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

Angular:

```
angular.module('root', [])
  .controller('index', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.messages = ["Hello", "Howdy", "What's up"]
  }

  .directive('myDirective', function() {
     return {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope: { greeting: '=' },
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var greeting = scope.greeting;  //one message from the array, fed in by <my-directive greeting='message'> from index.html
            var length = scope.messages.length; //length of whole messages array

            //do stuff
        }
      }
    }
```

HTML: (index.html)

```
   <body ng-app='root' ng-controller='index'>
    <div ng-repeat='message in messages'>
      <my-directive greeting='message'></my-directive> 
    </div>
</body>
```

I want to be able to access both the message and the "meta" information about the entire messages array from my link function. However, right now I can only access the message (var greeting) but the length variable does not evaluate.
Is there a way to do this in angular?

Let me know if you need any other clarifications!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules on isolate scopes are really simple, but hard to understand from the Angular docs.

If you omit the `scope:` property from the directive declaration, the directive will *share scope* with its parent. In other words, it will have direct access to the scope of the controller that called it, and all of its variables.

A better practice is to pass the necessary variables into the isolate scope, which you're already doing with the `greetings` variable. Your scope might look like this.

```
scope: {
  greeting: '=',
  messages: '='
}
```

Then write the directive like this:

`<my-directive greeting='message' messages='messages'></my-directive>`

And as long as `$scope.message` and `$scope.messages` are defined in your controller, you're all set.